# What can I do with xml duplicate elements with Smooks?

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, smooks

I m doing parse from xml to Java object. Here is the xml example:

```
<weather_data>
    <date>today</date>
    <weather>shower</weather>
    <date>tomorrow</date>
    <weather>snow</weather>
</weather_data>
```

That is to say, there are same elements like date and weather inside one weather_data
if I use createOnElement="weather_data/date", I can only get the last date value.
What should I do.
Thanks

Comment: Maybe you can rename the dates as "date1" and "date2"? And then use createOnElement="weather_data/date1" and createOnElement="weather_data/date2"?

Comment: I can not modify this coz it's from some public web api.